# Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3002, http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3002', but only one is allowed

Tags: javascript

I have downloaded a windows executable file and I installed it. The service will be listening on localhost:11100 port.

I have a written a javascript code to connect to the port and running this javascript code on any webserver is failing, because server sending multiple `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers in the response.

But if I write my JavaScript code in plain html page locally and open it in browser then it is sending one 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in the response.

Below is the `Javascript` code:

```
function RDService(){

var url = "http://127.0.0.1:11100";

var xhr;
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // If Internet Explorer, return version number{
    //IE browser
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} else {
    //other browser
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

xhr.open('RDSERVICE', url, true);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4){
            var status = xhr.status;

            if (status == 200) {

                alert(xhr.responseText);

        //Capture();                   //Call Capture() here if FingerPrint Capture is required inside RDService() call           
        console.log(xhr.response);

        } else {

            console.log(xhr.response);

        }
    }

};

xhr.send();
}
```

after calling the RDService function below error is throwing by the service:

> Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:11100/: Response to preflight request
>   doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header contains multiple values 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3002,
>   http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3002', but only one is allowed. Origin
>   'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3002' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: The problem is with your service running on localhost, not your JavaScript. The error is pretty specific, it's sending multiple hosts in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header when it should only send one.

Comment: The error states that the **response** headers are incorrect - your client code is irrelevant - `I have downloaded windows executable file and I installed it` - the fact that it is so poorly written should make you very nervous !!

Comment: @JaromandaX The code is connecting to a binary on localhost.

Comment: Yes, I understand ... but **response** headers come from the **server** - your **client** code is not responsible for the **response** headers, so the code is meaningless

Comment: so we are saying the same thing :)

Comment: please refer this https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score -1):

The windows executable should only be returning one domain or `*` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. This is not an issue with the client side JavaScript.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <origin>
```

`*`
For requests without credentials, the server may specify "*" as a wildcard, thereby allowing any origin to access the resource.
`<origin>`
Specifies a URI that may access the resource.

reference:
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted, it's the correct answer.